# How to hide Vertical scrollbar , but still able to scroll but not to hide vertical scroll bar

Tags: html

I use the following code to hide the vertical scroll bar , but it also hide my horizontal scroll bar

```
html {
    overflow: scroll !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Comment: there won't be any horizontal scrollbar because you have set `overflow-x:hidden`.

Comment: Is there a way to only custom overflow-y  let say width and colour

Answer (score 0):

```css
#container {
    background: wheat;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden !important;
}
#col {
    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
  The content of the document......
  <div id="container">
    <div id="col">
      1<br> 2
      <br> 3
      <br> 4
      <br> 5
      <br> 6
      <br> 7
      <br> 8
      <br> 9
      <br> 10
      <br> 11
      <br> 12
      <br> 13
      <br> 14
      <br> 15
      <br> 16
      <br> 17
      <br> 18
      <br> 19
      <br> 20
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Note:- You need to apply scroll on particular div and this example shows the good demo for the functionality you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use `overflow: auto` to automatically add scrollbar when the content is to large to fit inside a div. If you want to customize only for  horizontal or vertical scrolling, then go with `overflow-x: auto` or `overflow-y: auto`. Srollbar won't show up with `auto` value, if the content can easily fit inside the parent div.